# Reversing print order using recurion

Tags: recursion, printing, output, reverse

Right now, I have the following pseudocode

```
Printstations(fastest, path, lastpath, n)
 print "fastest solution requires" + fastest + "time units"
 print "line' + lastpath +"station" + n
 for j = n downto 2
      print "line" + path[lastpath, j] + "station" + j-1
      lastpath = path[lastpath, j]
```

a sample output would be:
     fastest solution requires 14 time units:
     line 1, station 4
     line 2, station 3
     line 2, station 2
     line 1, station 1

I need to reverse the order of that printout using recursion.
basically, I need it to read:
     fastest solution requires 14 time units:
     line 1, station 1
     line 2, station 2
     line 2, station 3
     line 1, station 4

Thanks.

So in essence, the station order needs to change from reading 4 down to 1 to being station 1 to 4, because of the sample, the line order doesn't appear to change but that it because in essence the line numbers here create a palindrome. I  haven't really been able to get anything coherent down yet. I am confused as to how recursion could change the order.

I came up with this:

```
PrintStations(fastest, path, lastpath, n)
 if n = 0
      print "fastest solution requires" + fastest + "time units"
 else
      PrintStations(fastest, path, path[lastpath, n], n-1)
      print "line" + lastpath + "station" + n
```

I think that may work, not entirely sure though.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your code to the question. Also the numbers in the second line are not the numbers from the first line in reverse...

Comment: One possibility would be calling Printstations from within Printstations with n - 1 and break execution when n == 1 or 0. In order to reverse the order you may need to store the original variable n for the break condition, somewhere outside of the function, and start from x = 1 and call Printstations with x + 1 until x == n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Your current output looks like this:

```
fastest solution requires 14 time units: 
    line 1, station 4 
    line 2, station 3 
    line 2, station 2 
    line 1, station 1
```

And you want to have such an output:

```
fastest solution requires 14 time units: 
    line 1, station 1 
    line 2, station 2 
    line 2, station 3 
    line 1, station 4
```

In order to achieve this using a recursion, you need to change your current solution:

```
PrintStations(fastest, path, lastpath, n)
    if n = 0
        COMMENT: incorrect, because this will be the last printed text,
        COMMENT: this line should be called once at the begining
        COMMENT: or even better before the recursive call is executed
        print "fastest solution requires" + fastest + "time units"
    else
        COMMENT: better change the order of the resursive call and the print
        PrintStations(fastest, path, path[lastpath, n], n-1)
        print "line" + lastpath + "station" + n
```

This will print the line **faster solution requires ...** at the end of the execution and not at the begining. I am assuming that you start with n and not 0, because if you start with 0 the resursive call is never reached.

A general approach using recursion is to extract the function that calls itself and execute it initially from another function, because you need a start point.
You can create a function called **PrintSolution**, that takes the same arguments as your **PrintStations** function and call the **PrintStations** once from within. 
This would be also the right place to print the **fastest solution ...** text:

```
COMMENT: this is now your starting point
PrintSolution(fastest, path, lastpath, n)
    print "fastest solution requires" + fastest + "time units"
    PrintStations(fastest, path lastpath, n)
```

Your **PrintStations** will also become smaller and easier to write/read:

```
PrintStations(fastest, path, lastpath, n)
    COMMENT: execution break condition is n == 0
    if n > 0
        COMMENT: print current path and station
        print "line" + lastpath + "station" + n
        COMMENT: call print station with next/previous path to print
        PrintStations(fastest, path, path[lastpath, n], n-1)
```

There are of course other possibilities to create the recursive function. A solution that does not require a second function could look like this:

```
variable m = n
PrintStations(fastest, path, lastpath, n)
    COMMENT: execution break condition is n == 0
    if (n = m)
        COMMENT: first call
        print "fastest solution requires" + fastest + "time units"          
    if n > 0
        COMMENT: print current path and station
        print "line" + lastpath + "station" + n
        COMMENT: call print station with next/previous path to print
        PrintStations(fastest, path, path[lastpath, n], n-1)
```

In this case you need the initial value of the n variable in order to print the first line only once.

The resursive call is equivalent to the iteration, because it operates also sequentially on the given data structure:

```
print(3);

COMMENT: equivalent to for (i = 3; i <= 1; i--) => 3 -> 2 -> 1
for i = 3 downto 1
    out i

COMMENT: 3 -> 2 -> 1
print(n)
    if (n > 0)
        print(n-1);
        out n

COMMENT: reverse the print - 1 -> 2 -> 3
variable m = n
print(n)
    if (n <= m)
        print(n+1);
        out n
```

Another possibility would be to give the break condition constant as a parameter:

```
print(n, m)
    if (n <= m)
        print(n+1, m);
        out n
COMMENT: initial call: print(1, 3)
```

Without precise description and more information (or at least the data) about the **path** array, it is difficult to write a working solution, but the pseudocode goes in the right direction.